# Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix. If for all singular $n \times n$ matrices $C$, $AC=0$. Then does $A=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I think this is true as I tried to come up with a counterexamples but couldn't.
Is there a way to prove it? I can't think of a proof.
Thanks.

Comment: **Hint:** If $AC_1 = 0$ and $AC_2 = 0$, then $A(C_1 + C_2) = 0$ (btw, why do you need $A$ to be symmetric?)

Comment: @Daniel Nice one! Didn't even think of that.

Comment: @Daniel, This is a subpart of another question. I didn't know how to proceed for this question, hence i included it.

Answer (score 1):

If $n = 1$, the only singular matrix is $C = 0$ but then any matrix $A$ will satisfy $AC = 0$ and not only $A = 0$.

For $n > 1$, denote by $e_1,\dots,e_n$ the standard basis of $\mathbb{F}^n$. Choose $1 \leq i \leq n$ and consider a matrix $C$ whose columns are the same and equal to $e_i$. This is a singular matrix (it has rank $1 < n$) and $AC$ is a matrix whose columns are $Ae_i, \dots, Ae_i$. By assumption, $Ae_i = 0$ and since this is true for all $1 \leq i \leq n$, we get $A = 0$. Note that we haven't used the fact that $A$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

For $n=1$, $\boldsymbol{c}=\boldsymbol0$ hence $\boldsymbol{a} = \boldsymbol0$.

For $n=2$, have you tried $$\boldsymbol C = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}?$$
Can we generalize this to the more general case?

Comment: but the question says for all singular matrices not just these ones.

Comment: @JohnKutta For all means for these including, using these we can derive that $\boldsymbol A = \boldsymbol O$.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like we didn't even the condition that A is symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Basis $C_1,C_2,..., C_{n^2}$ of $M_{n \times n}$ such that each $C_j$ is singular. For the identity matrix $I$ we have

$I=\sum_{k=0}^{n^2}s_kC_k$ for some scalars $s_k$.

Then $A=\sum_{k=0}^{n^2}s_kAC_k=0$

(symmetry was not needed)

Comment: Why this basis? I was thinking in taking $C_j$ as the matrix with a $1$ as entry $j,j$ and $0$s elsewhere. We'd have $n$ of these singular matrices and their sum would equal the identity. (Maybe you wanted to include a basis that generates not only the identity, but all the matrices?)

Comment: @Daniel Notice that the basis he is saying or even the collection you wanted doesn't always exist.

Comment: @Marja Sure? I guess it does not for $n=1$, but otherwise it looks pretty trivial to obtain such basis

Comment: @Daniel That is why I said "... doens't always exist".